# SQL Server login failure in middle of application run

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008

I have an application that suddenly started throwing the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'username'.

The username and password are correct and the app does some queries/inserts using the same login before throwing the exception.

What are some other reasons a login can start failing?  Does SQL Server have a default maximum number of connections that may have been reached?  I'm using LINQ to SQL - does the fact that I'm reusing a DataContext to insert multiple rows of data rather than creating a new one each time have any relevant consequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was with the way I was creating DataContexts - I was keeping one around in the class and creating a new method-local one every time I did an update (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150796/linq-to-sql-duplicatekeyexception-during-update) for more details).  I just refactored the code to create a new DataContext for each transaction and the error went away.

Answer (score 3):

Using the same `DataContext` for multiple sequential operations is just fine, but make sure you're not sharing the `DataContext` among multiple threads.  If, for example, you're creating an ASP.NET application, make sure that each new request uses its own `DataContext`.