# linq2sql DuplicateKeyExceptionwhile doing an update

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to do an update on a record in my database using linq2sql, however, I am getting the following exception thrown:

```
 'System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException' in System.Data.Linq.dll ("Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.")   System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException
```

Although I understand what the exception is telling me, how is this possible when doing an update? I am not inserting any data so realistically no keys should be updated?

```
 var Printer = db.Printers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == i.PrinterId);
 Printer.CenterId = GetCenterId(i.NewCenterCode);
 Printer.LastCenterCode = i.NewCenterCode;
 db.SubmitChanges();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `CenterId`  have a unique constraint ? Do you do any operations with your `db` context before the piece of code that you've shown ?

Comment: @user3185569 or `LastCenterCode` for that matter

Comment: Neither of them have a unique constraint, the only 2 unique columns are ID (primary key) and MacAddress (which in this case is not being updated)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are using your dbcontext 'too much' and that the dbcontext is already managing the same record you are trying to update.

Try using a new dbcontext to perform the update. Dbcontexts are meant to be created used and disposed frequently.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3151724/711061

Comment: This very well may be the case, my app filters a CSV with around 60k records and I am creating a single dbcontext per class. I am running a large number of loops so is it best to create a new context within each loop?

Comment: Well.. no. A dbcontext should be used locally to perform as much atomic work as possible. You decide what's atomic and minimal. I'd use a single dbcontext for the loop, and maybe for the entire update method.