# Linq to SQL FirstOrDefault does not execute the SQL query

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Windows Forms. I instanciate my data context in the form's constructor. I want to display information about article when I click on a button. Data can be updated externally. The problem is that, in this case, data is not refreshed.

I already know that re-instanciate my data context each time is an option. ToList would force to get the refreshed data. But I really thought that FirstOrDefault() would execute SQL each time...

I did some log and this is not the case. Is there an option over there to force the SQL execution? Is there a sort of cache here?

```
using (var log = new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\\LOG.TXT", true))
{
    DB.Log = log;

    var article = DB.T_Articles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NumArticle == 11);
    MessageBox.Show(article.Description);

    var articles = DB.T_Articles.ToList();

    log.WriteLine("----------------------------------");

    DB.Log = null;
}
```

Here is the log file. We can see that the SQL behind the FirstOrDefault method is here. We can see that it disappears the second time

```
SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[NumArticle], [t0].[EAN13], [t0].[Minimum], [t0].[Emplacement], [t0].[Fournisseur], [t0].[Qte], [t0].[Description], [t0].[Photo], [t0].[Prix], [t0].[IsEmail]
FROM [dbo].[T_Article] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[NumArticle] = @p0
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [11]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.7.2046.0

SELECT [t0].[NumArticle], [t0].[EAN13], [t0].[Minimum], [t0].[Emplacement], [t0].[Fournisseur], [t0].[Qte], [t0].[Description], [t0].[Photo], [t0].[Prix], [t0].[IsEmail]
FROM [dbo].[T_Article] AS [t0]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.7.2046.0

----------------------------------
SELECT [t0].[NumArticle], [t0].[EAN13], [t0].[Minimum], [t0].[Emplacement], [t0].[Fournisseur], [t0].[Qte], [t0].[Description], [t0].[Photo], [t0].[Prix], [t0].[IsEmail]
FROM [dbo].[T_Article] AS [t0]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.7.2046.0

----------------------------------
```

Comment: What tool are you using to generate that log file based on the executing SQL? If you run a SQL Trace do you see the TOP 1 query executing multiple times?

Comment: Please show your code for `T_Articles`.

Comment: @mjwills I use a dbml file I'm not sure it would help. The TOP(1) is only present the first time

Comment: I did some Googling on this, and apparently Linq2Sql is smart enough to check its cache for the primary key that you're looking for. So in this case, it assumes nothing has changed and doesn't bother with the query. You can use a `Refresh()` to get around this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664910/linq-to-sql-does-not-update-when-data-has-changed-in-database).

Comment: @JonB well that sucks :) Smart enough but in this case it display inconsistent data...

Answer (score 3):

You may try to refresh your context each time before FirstOrDefault():

```
Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, [table_name]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reload the found entry , read more about  [cache busting](http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/)

```
  var article = DB.T_Articles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NumArticle == 11);
  DB.Entry(article).Reload();
```